# Issue in adding new OID , receiving some garbage value

Tags: net-snmp, mib, oid

I have added a new node to the existing MIB tree. In the MIB definition file it is Counter32 as this will be unsigned long in c file. I have used data type in OID as ASN_COUNTER in c file  and returning a hardcoded value. but when i do snmpwalk, snmpget or use ireasoning mib browser to see value, it gives me some garbage value.

Can someone please help if i am missing something?

I am making changed in net snmp customized software.

thanks.

Comment: while when i change the datatype in c file to long it works fine for me. but unsigned long gives me garbage value.  very strange!

Comment: Very hard to help without seeing any code. If it's a big application, try reproducing the problem in a smaller example like described in http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve